# After changing ID of div it still refers to old element (jQuery/JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three div elements that has a close button (simplified):

```
<div class="box1" id="box1">
    <span>close</span>
</div>

<div class="box2" id="box2">
    <span>close</span>
</div>

<div class="box3" id="box3">
    <span>close</span>
</div>
```

If I click the close button, box 1 will be removed via the 
jquery `removed()` function. Consequently, the class of box 2 will be `box1`, as well as its ID. The same thing goes for the box 3 whose ID and CLASS will become `box2`.

I used add and remove class, as well as `attr('oldID','newID')` functions to 
achieve this. The problem is, when I try to access the new box 1 (formerly box 2) and use something like `$('#box1').fadeOut()`, the one that disappears is box 2 
(formerly box 3).

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Can you post your js please?

Comment: pls show your code, because wheter removed() function exists nor attr() works like you describe

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: Okay thanks, i'll make a fiddle real quick

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/g18bhkkt/5/ here's my fiddle

Comment: I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**removed()** is not a jQuery function. Instead, the jQuery method [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) is used to remove the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Please, consider the ID must be unique and there is no need to change them. You may simply work on classes.

Consider to avoid global variables and to use data attribute to preserve ordering.

Your jsfiddle can be reduced to:

```js
$('.header').on('click', function(e) {
    //
    // decide the animation direction....
    //
    var newBottom = ($(this).closest('.box').css('bottom') == '-180px') ? '0px' : '-180px';
    $(this).closest('.box').animate({'bottom':newBottom}, 200);
});

$('.close').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.box').remove();
    $('.close').each(function(idx, ele) {
        var classNames = ['', 'second', 'third'];
        //
        // toggle classes
        //
        $(this).closest('.box').toggleClass(classNames[this.dataset.sortOrder - 1] + ' ' + classNames[idx]);
        var sortOrder = idx + 1;
        this.dataset.sortOrder = sortOrder;
        //
        // adjust titles
        //
        $(this).prev('.title').text(function(idx, txt) {
            return txt.replace(/\d$/, sortOrder)
        })
    })
});
```

```css
.box {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 20px #D8D8D8;
}

.second {
    right: 200px;
}

.third {
    right: 370px;
}

.header {
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    cursor : pointer;
}

.title {
    float:left;
    background: #53DD6C;
}

.close {
    float:right;
    cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box" id="first-box">
   <span class="header" id="first-header">
     <span class="title">Box 1</span>
     <span class="close" data-sort-order="1" id="first-close">X</span>
   </span>
</div>


<div class="box second" id="second-box">
   <span class="header" id="second-header">
     <span class="title">Box 2</span>
     <span class="close" data-sort-order="2" id="second-close">X</span>
   </span>
</div>



<div class="box third" id="third-box">
   <span class="header" id="third-header">
     <span class="title">Box 3</span>
     <span class="close" data-sort-order="3" id="third-close">X</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask you for any suggestions about my fiddle ?

Comment: Sir gaetanoM, I copy pasted and adjusted your code to my fiddle but box2 and box3 closes at the same time. :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your jsfiddle, it looks like a lot of overkill. You should be able to manage each element with one common function.

```js
$('.header').on('click', function() {
    // Add or remove the 'expanded' class
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    var boxId = $(this).attr('id').substring('header-'.length);
    
    // Set up the new bottom for animation
    var bottomPx = '-180px';
    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
        bottomPx = '0px';
    }
    
    $('#' + boxId).animate({'bottom':bottomPx}, 200);
});

$('.close').on('click', function() {
    var boxId = $(this).attr('id').substring('close-'.length);
    $('#' + boxId).remove();
});
```

```css
.box {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 20px #D8D8D8; 
}

.second {
  right: 200px;
}

.third {
  right: 370px;
}

.header {
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  cursor : pointer;
}

.title {
 float:left;
 background: #53DD6C;
}

.close {
  float:right;
  cursor : pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="box" id="box1">
   <span class="header expanded" id="header-box1">
     <span class="title">Box 1</span>
     <span class="close" id="close-box1">X</span>
   </span>
 </div>
 
  <div class="box second" id="box2">
   <span class="header expanded" id="header-box2">
     <span class="title">Box 2</span>
     <span class="close" id="close-box2">X</span>
   </span>
 </div>
 
  <div class="box third" id="box3">
   <span class="header expanded" id="header-box3">
     <span class="title">Box 3</span>
     <span class="close" id="close-box3">X</span>
   </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Updated my answer with code based on your jsfiddle. See lines after "Edit 1".